# Apply hierachial shuffling/sorting of data frame in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have data frame where I want to shuffle or more generally sort the values hierachially but I am stuck. Here is my example:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:4], each = 10), b = rnorm(40))
> head(df)
  a          b
1 a -0.1264280
2 a  0.7284234
3 a -1.8782385
4 a  0.2530623
5 a  0.7577013
6 a -0.9339964
```

In this example, I want to suffle (sample) the values but only within the letters so that a value assigned to the letter a in colum a cannot be assigned to any other letter but only to a different a row but not b, c or d.

I've tried this `ddply(df, c('a'), b = sample(b))` but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, `group_by(a)` then use `mutate(b = sample(b))`

```
library(dplyr)
head(df, 10)
   a           b
1  a -0.56047565
2  a -0.23017749
3  a  1.55870831
4  a  0.07050839
5  a  0.12928774
6  a  1.71506499
7  a  0.46091621
8  a -1.26506123
9  a -0.68685285
10 a -0.44566197

df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b = sample(b))
# A tibble: 40 x 2
# Groups:   a [4]
   a           b
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 a      1.56  
 2 a      0.461 
 3 a      0.0705
 4 a      1.72  
 5 a     -0.560 
 6 a     -0.446 
 7 a     -1.27  
 8 a      0.129 
 9 a     -0.230 
10 a     -0.687 
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Even `ddply(df, c('a'), mutate, b = sample(b))` seem to work. This is so useful to know.

Comment: For fun...here's a solution using `tapply` in base R: `data.frame(a = df$a, b = unlist(tapply(df$b,df$a,sample)))`